# React Component for Appending Data to Google Sheet working on PC but not on iOS or Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, google-sheets-api

I have a React app with the following component for appending rows to a Google Sheet.  The component works perfectly on a PC running Windows 10.  On my iPad and Pixel 3, I get the Google signin screen when I click "Sign In" but when I click "Save" to execute the API call to append, nothing happens.  I have used an alert in debugging to determine that the execute() function is getting called.  But it doesn't append the data or get to the .then block.  Help!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { get } from "../helpers/localStorage"

const SPREADSHEET_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID
const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_SHEETS_API_KEY
const SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"

export default function AddGuestToGoogleSheet() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ gapi: null })
  let ghinNumber = get("ghinNumber")
  let guests = get("guests")

  useEffect(() => {
    require("google-client-api")().then((gapi) => {
      setState({ gapi: gapi })
    })
  }, [state.gapi])

  function handleSignInClick() {
    if (state.gapi !== null) {
      authenticate().then(loadClient)
    }
  }

  function handleSaveClick() {
    if (state.gapi !== null) {
      execute()
    }
  }

  function authenticate() {
    return state.gapi.auth2
      .getAuthInstance()
      .signIn({
        scope: SCOPE,
      })
      .then(
        function () {
          console.log("Sign-in successful")
        },
        function (err) {
          console.error("Error signing in", err)
        }
      )
  }
  function loadClient() {
    state.gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY)
    return state.gapi.client
      .load("https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4")
      .then(
        function () {
          console.log("GAPI client loaded for API")
        },
        function (err) {
          console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err)
        }
      )
  }

  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return state.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values
      .append({
        spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
        range: ghinNumber + "!A1:A3",
        includeValuesInResponse: true,
        insertDataOption: "INSERT_ROWS",
        responseDateTimeRenderOption: "FORMATTED_STRING",
        responseValueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE",
        valueInputOption: "RAW",
        resource: {
          values: guests,
        },
      })
      .then(
        function (response) {
          localStorage.removeItem("guests")
          document.location = "/settings/logout"
          // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
          console.log("Response", response)
        },
        function (err) {
          console.error("Execute error", err)
        }
      )
  }

  if (state.gapi !== null) {
    state.gapi.load("client:auth2", function () {
      state.gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      })
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="div--center div--bordered">
        <h4>
          To save your guest(s) to your table
          <br />
          of players in Google Sheets
        </h4>
        <button className="button" onClick={handleSignInClick}>
          Sign In
        </button>
        <span className="span_then--bold"> then </span>
        <button className="button" onClick={handleSaveClick}>
          Save
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Welcome! To prevent a faulty device authentication, could you please check the OAuth 2.0 flow on your mobile devices? If they are correctly authenticated, please share the 
API call/response pair.

Comment: Thanks, Jacques-Guzel Heron.  You put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to "authenticate()" in handleSignInClick and then "loadClient().then(execute)" in handleSaveClick.  This works on my PC, iPad, and Pixel 3.